# Convert multiple columns into a MultiIndex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

A library I use returns a DataFrame for analysis. This DataFrame is a simple time series with multiple columns. I would like to join a couple of these columns to a MultiIndex and export the result as a JSON file.

Example:

```
In[2]: df.loc[:, ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close']].tail()
Out[2]: 
                               open      high       low     close
period_close                                                     
2018-08-20 23:56:00+00:00  0.001837  0.001837  0.001837  0.001837
2018-08-20 23:57:00+00:00  0.001837  0.001837  0.001837  0.001837
2018-08-20 23:58:00+00:00  0.001837  0.001841  0.001830  0.001841
2018-08-20 23:59:00+00:00  0.001827  0.001840  0.001814  0.001832
2018-08-21 00:00:00+00:00  0.001824  0.001831  0.001824  0.001831
```

I would like to transform this table into the following format:

```
                                                             candle
period_close                                                     
2018-08-20 23:56:00+00:00  [0.001837, 0.001837, 0.001837, 0.001837]
2018-08-20 23:57:00+00:00  [0.001837, 0.001837, 0.001837, 0.001837]
2018-08-20 23:58:00+00:00  [0.001837, 0.001841, 0.001830, 0.001841]
2018-08-20 23:59:00+00:00  [0.001827, 0.001840, 0.001814, 0.001832]
2018-08-21 00:00:00+00:00  [0.001824, 0.001831, 0.001824, 0.001831]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recreate your data frame

```
Newdf=pd.DataFrame({'candle':df.values.tolist()},index=df.index)
Newdf
Out[221]: 
                                                                     candle
period_close                                                               
2018-08-2023:56:00+00:00           [0.001837, 0.001837, 0.001837, 0.001837]
2018-08-2023:57:00+00:00           [0.001837, 0.001837, 0.001837, 0.001837]
2018-08-2023:58:00+00:00            [0.001837, 0.001841, 0.00183, 0.001841]
2018-08-2023:59:00+00:00  [0.001827, 0.0018399999999999998, 0.001814, 0....
2018-08-2100:00:00+00:00  [0.0018239999999999999, 0.001831, 0.0018239999...
```